# Expose individual Kafka brokers on Kubernetes through an ELB on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-kafka, kubernetes, amazon-elb

I am running a KOPS Kubernetes cluster on AWS, trying to make [kubernetes-kafka](https://github.com/Yolean/kubernetes-kafka) example work with an Elastic Load Balancer. Here is the external services portion for two of the brokers:

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: outside-0
  namespace: kafka
spec:
  selector:
    app: kafka
    kafka-broker-id: "0"
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 9094
    port: 32400
    nodePort: 32400
  type: NodePort
---
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: outside-1
  namespace: kafka
spec:
  selector:
    app: kafka
    kafka-broker-id: "1"
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 9094
    port: 32401
    nodePort: 32401
  type: NodePort
```

Here is my attempt to expose those brokers via an ELB (actual FQDN replaced with `my.copmany.com`).

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: kafka-0
  annotations:
    dns.alpha.kubernetes.io/external: kafka-0.kafka.my.company.com
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - port: 32400
    name: outside
    targetPort: 32400
  selector:
    app: outside-0
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: kafka-1
  annotations:
    dns.alpha.kubernetes.io/external: kafka-1.kafka.my.company.com
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - port: 32401
    name: outside
    targetPort: 32401
  selector:
    app: outside-1
```

Looking at AWS ELB console shows 0 of 3 instances available for each of the Kafka ELB brokers and producing to `kafka-1.kafka.my.company.com:9094` using Kafka command line client times out. How can `outside-0` NodePort service be exposed via `kafka-0` LoadBalancer service? Or are there other approached to be considered?

Comment: Maybe this helps https://stackoverflow.com/q/41868161/741970

Comment: @DmitryMinkovsky - thank you for the link, both of the top answers there have some good elements to them, first one exposes it through `ec2-host:port` and the second one uses `elb:port`. My challenge is each kafka broker needs to have it's own "permanent" URL like `subdomain-on-company-domain:port`, e.g. `kafka-1.kafka.my.company.com:9094`.

Comment: Yeah I've never quite figured it out myself. Fortunately in my situation I ended up realizing I could send data out from inside instead of opening Kafka up to the outside. If you figure this out, please post an answer.

Comment: The ELB DNS is permanent for the service. It will not change if you redeploy or even remove the deployment. It will be released if you delete the service. If you own your own DNS such as my.kafka.com you can alias it to the ELB DNS

Answer (score 5):

Kakfa is very particular about clients needing direct access to the server who is the leader of a topic. To achieve this, I had done the following:

1) Setup the configmap to dynamically override values for the advertised.listeners based on the pod's ordinal value

```
POD_ID=${HOSTNAME##*-}

kafka-server-start.sh server.properties \
      --override advertised.listeners=INSIDE://`hostname -f`:9092,OUTSIDE://kafka-${POD_ID}.kafka.my.company.com:9094 \
      --override broker.id=${POD_ID} \
      --override listeners=INSIDE://:9092,OUTSIDE://:9094
```

2) Create a LoadBalancer service for each Kafka pod. Change the selector to match your kafka-pod-id.

```
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: Service
    metadata:
      name: kafka-0
      annotations:
        dns.alpha.kubernetes.io/external: kafka-0.kafka.my.company.com
    spec:
      externalTrafficPolicy: Local
      type: LoadBalancer
      ports:
      - port: 9094
        name: outside
        targetPort: 9094
      selector:
        app: kafka
        kafka-pod-id: "0"
---     
apiVersion: v1
        kind: Service
        metadata:
          name: kafka-1
          annotations:
            dns.alpha.kubernetes.io/external: kafka-1.kafka.my.company.com
        spec:
          externalTrafficPolicy: Local
          type: LoadBalancer
          ports:
          - port: 9094
            name: outside
            targetPort: 9094
          selector:
            app: kafka
            kafka-pod-id: "1"
```

Answer (score 4):

These Kubernetes configurations look correct. However, if the AWS console says "0 of 3 instances available" that usually means that you're failing the ELB healthcheck. The ELB will drop any traffic if there's not a healthy backend instance available to send the data to, which would explain the calls to Kafka timing out.

An easy ELB healthcheck for nodeport services is just SSH to see if the instance itself is alive, since kube-proxy on that instance is what is actually going to forward the traffic to the right instance. If you're only running one listener on the ELB, then you could actually check that port in your healthcheck. (I often run a bunch of nodeport listeners per ELB instead of one per nodeport service to save money.)

Answer (score 3):

According to the documentation ([Kuebrnetes Service Types](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#publishing-services---service-types)):

> LoadBalancer: Exposes the service externally using a cloud provider’s
>   load balancer. NodePort and ClusterIP services, to which the external
>   load balancer will route, are automatically created.

You should not be defining separate services for NodePort and LoadBalancer types, but only `LoadBalancer` with `nodePort` specified (Please test and try to add/remove some options since I don't have an environment I could test this on):

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: kafka-0
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - port: 32400
    name: kafka
    nodePort: 32400
  selector:
    app: kafka
    kafka-broker-id: "0"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: kafka-1
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - port: 32401
    name: kafka
    nodePort: 32401
  selector:
    app: kafka
    kafka-broker-id: "1"
```

- Kubernetes cluster should have AWS API access configured. `kubelet`, `kube-apiserver`, `kube-controller-manager/cloud-controller-manager` have cloud configuration options.

Answer (score 1):

The target port is not set correctly, you have to use the container port and a NodePort will be automatically assigned. The configuration looks like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: kafka-0
  annotations:
    dns.alpha.kubernetes.io/external: kafka-0.kafka.my.company.com
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - port: 9094
    name: outside
    targetPort: 9094
  selector:
    app: outside-0
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: kafka-1
  annotations:
    dns.alpha.kubernetes.io/external: kafka-1.kafka.my.company.com
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - port: 9094
    name: outside
    targetPort: 9094
  selector:
    app: outside-1
```

The external port can be anything you want, for example you can use 9094, same as container's port and it can be the same port for all services, because you use different ELBs. Just make sure the selectors are set correctly and this should work fine.